# Proceed to next activity through radio buttons on alert dialog

Tags: android, android-intent, radio-button, android-alertdialog

I have listview ,on click of each list item, it must pop up a alert with radio buttons. Selecting a radio button option and then clicking "ok" button on alert dialog , I must be able to proceed to next activity. (PS i dont want to use positive , negative button ).

Below is my code, listview is working fine , alert dialog pops up and on selecting yes or no , Toast shows .But upon yes it isn't proceeding to next activity. Please help!!

```
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
    final String[] items = new String[]{"IOS", "ANDROID", "WINDOWS"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, items);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            int itemposition = position;
            String itemvalue = (String) listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
            final CharSequence[] items1 = {"yes", "no"};
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("slection confirmation");
            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items1, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items1[which], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            });
            builder.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch(items1.toString())
                    {
                        case("yes"):
                            Intent myint=new Intent(MainActivity.this,secondpage.class);
                            myint.putExtra("act1","");
                            startActivity(myint);
                            break;
                        case("no"):
                            dialog.cancel();

                    }
               }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem in below code snippet, As you covert whole string array into string , but you need to get one item at time.

```
 switch(items1.toString())
                    {
                        case("yes"):
                            Intent myint=new Intent(MainActivity.this,secondpage.class);
                            myint.putExtra("act1","");
                            startActivity(myint);
                            break;
                        case("no"):
                            dialog.cancel();

                    }
```

Please replace this with

```
String selection;
     listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                int itemposition = position;
                String itemvalue = (String) listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
                final CharSequence[] items1 = {"yes", "no"};
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("slection confirmation");
                builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items1, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    selection = items1[which]
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items1[which], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                });
                builder.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch(selection)
                        {
                            case("yes"):
                                Intent myint=new Intent(MainActivity.this,secondpage.class);
                                myint.putExtra("act1","");
                                startActivity(myint);
                                break;
                            case("no"):
                                dialog.cancel();

                        }
                   }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: thank you very much . it worked , but when I used String selection inside setsinglechoiceitems loop it gave me error to use 'final',when i used 'final' it gave me error that final shouldnt be used .so made that String selection global and it is working fine :)

Comment: Oh yes, we have to make this variable as global , I edit this answer and  please accept this if worked

Comment: the above code will lead me from first page(MainActivity) to second activity (secondpage) no matter which list item I choose. how to code it such that I can navigate each listitem to different activity